# Difference between "run-of-the-mill" and "garden-variety"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms

The "[run-of-the-mill](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/run-of-the-mill)" (*average or ordinary* / [etymologyy](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=run-of-the-mill)) entry on *Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary* contains a reference to "*often disapproving*". The "[garden-variety](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/garden-variety)" (*not unusual; ordinary or common* / [etymology](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=garden)) entry doesn't, but mentions "*always used before a noun US*". The latter can be found as a [synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/run-of-the-mill) of the former; and *vice versa*, but to a [lesser](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/garden-variety?s=t) extent.

Are those differences correct and generally acknowledged by the native speaker and are there further differences between "*run-of-the-mill*" and "*garden-variety*" I should be aware of (intensity, usage, register, categories of objects it can relate to etc.)?

Comment: I would say that "run-of-the-mill" is not necessarily disapproving, but it does imply _no better than average_, and possibly _worse than average_ quality.  "Garden-variety", however, implies only that the item is of a type commonly/easily found. You might want to also compare "dime a dozen", which connotes cheapness as well as easy availability; or "plain vanilla", which means unadorned and unmodified—the standard edition.

Comment: Run-of-the-mill definitely suggests humdrum (dullness), whereas garden variety does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference as you suggested is the tone associated with the phrases. "run-of-the-mill" definitely suggests a more dull, negative tone than "garden-variety" does. However, I have seen Americans use them interchangeably, whether it was on purpose or just because of ignorance I do not know. 
Eg: The novel I read was a run-of-the-mill detective thriller.
(versus)
This garden-variety dress robe would blend in with any decor.